# is it possible to automatically delete a row in a table if a certain condition is met?

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to automatically delete a row in a table if a certain condition is met?

for example a products table

```
pid     pname     quantity
1       shoes     5
```

now the condition must be if quantity is equal to 0 then the whole row must be deleted

Answer (score 2):

Issue the query `DELETE FROM table WHERE quantity = 0` and all rows satisfying the condition will be deleted.